# i need to read rdf in javascript

Tags: javascript, rdf

i need to read rdf file in javascript urgently

Comment: Too urgent to google it? Hmmm...

Comment: The question is a bit vague indeed.

Answer (score 8):

[JavaScript RDF Parser](http://www.jibbering.com/rdf-parser/)

Comment: He needs it urgently though! +1 though for the acronym, even if it's Google's first result

Comment: how do you actually use that thing, i.e. [what about this situation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33791217/how-to-tweak-this-javascript-file-to-read-in-my-data-on-localhost-parsing-rdf-t)

Answer (score 0):

Other answers already pointed you to an rdf parser.

Should you need something more, here's a very nice Node.js based RDF store with SPARQL support: https://github.com/antoniogarrote/rdfstore-js.